# Unable to load timezones?

Tags: mysql, database

I am attempting to load timezones into my MySql instance (that is running on Ubuntu) so that I can use the CONVERT_TZ function but when I run the command below:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

I get the following output and when I try to use `CONVERT_TZ` it just returns `NULL` still:

> Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh87' as time
>   zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh89' as time
>   zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh88' as time
>   zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time
>   zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Riyadh88' as
>   time zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Mideast/Riyadh87'
>   as time zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Mideast/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping
>   it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Mideast/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping
>   it. Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Riyadh87'
>   as time zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
>   Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Riyadh89' as
>   time zone. Skipping it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Mideast/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping
>   it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Mideast/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping
>   it. Warning: Unable to load
>   '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Mideast/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping
>   it. Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time
>   zone. Skipping it.

Does anyone have an idea why this would be happening?

PS:

I'm using the following method to convert datetimes:

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'UTC', 'PCT')
```

Is it possible that I'm just converting incorrectly and that is the cause of the NULL results?

Comment: The first command in your pipeline, this `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` script, emits a big ugly .sql file if you don't pipe it straight into `mysql`. What does that file look like?  Do you need the historic Saudi Arabian timezone data?

Comment: No, basically I will only be converting from UTC to PST.  I'm guessing you don't want me to post the whole big ugly sql script.  Is there something specific I should be looking for in the .sql file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a bug with the timezone files for Riyadh* on Debian:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20545

The recommended workaround is to simply ignore the warning (if you don't need those timezone of course):

```bsh
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/lib/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot --force mysql
```

After importing TZ data with the `--force` option, you will be able to use `CONVERT_TZ`. Here is a transcription of what I've just done:

```bsh
sh$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot -p mysql --force 2> /dev/null
Enter password: ********
sh$ mysql -p
Enter password: ********
Server version: 5.1.49-3 (Debian)

mysql> select convert_tz(now(), 'UTC', 'CET');
+---------------------------------+
| convert_tz(now(), 'UTC', 'CET') |
+---------------------------------+
| 2013-08-13 21:04:34             |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It looks like I had everything I needed installed, but was getting null because I was converting to `PST` instead of `PST8PDT`...

Comment: @AbeMiessler :D In case of doubt on a TZ name, you could query `mysql.time_zone_name` for a quick check. If your particular case: `select name from mysql.time_zone_name where name like '%PST%';`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Sylvain's solution didn't worked for me.

I was able to populate the timezone tables of our production server by exporting the tables from the `PHPMyAdmin` of my development computer (on Windows) and tweaking the creation script a little bit.

Since the script is too long to be shared in a post, I will host it on my Google Drive.

The install script (with new lines and comments stripped):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7iwL5F-hwr_YkItRXk2Z1VZdlE/view?usp=sharing

The script with comments:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7iwL5F-hwr_dWdjTDREcXNHQmM/view?usp=sharing

Make sure to use the version without comments. The comment version take about 5 minutes to run and end up failing for some reason while the stripped version take less than 5 seconds to run.

**Note**: You'll probably need to run as `root` in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan Parent Lévesque, you saved my day.