# Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.dates()

Tags: mysql, django, timezone, mezzanine

I get this error on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine with mysql 5.5 after I imported some Wordpress content to Mezzanine's blog_blogpost.

```
ValueError at /admin/blog/blogpost/
Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.dates(). Are time zone definitions and pytz installed?

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogpost/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.dates(). Are time zone definitions and pytz installed?
Exception Location: /home/me/.mezenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in results_iter, line 1107
Python Executable:  /home/me/.mezenv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
[u'/home/me',
 '/home/me/sai',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/me/.mezenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 25 Jan 2014 13:44:11 +0100


Error during template rendering

In template /home/me/.mezenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli_safe/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 140
```

I added to my local_settings.py

```
import pytz
from pytz import *
```

and also defined timezone in my.cnf [mysqld]

```
default-time-zone = "+01:00"
```

but I still get the error unitl I get the line in template:

the tag is:

> 140    {% block date_hierarchy %}{% date_hierarchy cl %}{% endblock %}

Appreciate your help to resolve it.

Answer (score 122):

Looks like error caused [Django's 1.6 timezone functionality changes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#time-zone-definitions). The docs now mention this error specifically ([bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21629), [link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting)).

You have to load timezone tables into mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).
Try execute on your database server:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -u root -p
```

And then run "flush tables" or "flush query cache", otherwise the problem may not disappear even though you've loaded the correct timezone data:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "flush tables;" mysql
```

updated by @qris

Comment: If it doesn't work on your Debian, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18216945/1161025

Comment: In my case I had also to add

    import pytz  and
    from pytz import *

Wouldn't work without it. Although after removing these imports its still working fine. Weird

Comment: Note for whoever comes across this problem now: this solution will still work perfectly fine with Django 1.8.

Comment: Works fine on Django 1.11.

Answer (score 20):

What worked for me:

**1. Populate the timezone definitions in the 'mysql' table**

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

**2. Flush tables**

```
mysql -u root -p -e "flush tables;" mysql
```

**3. Restart mysql**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 16):

For MacOS users I found solution [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html) (in comment):

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | sed -e "s/Local time zone must be set--see zic manual page/local/" | mysql -u root mysql
```

Because on MacOS we have error looks like this:

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u roomysql

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/+VERSION' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 38981: Data too long for column 'Abbreviation' at row 1
```

Answer (score 9):

For Windows, take the following steps:

- stop the service
- download the [files provided by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) but note they go in
   `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server VERSION\data\mysql`
   *not* in
   `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server VERSION\data`
   at least on Windows 7 as of 2014.
- I also modified C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server VERSION\my.ini to add `default-time-zone = 'UTC'` per [the tips here](http://www.pending.io/django-mysql-time-zones-and-how-to-fix-it/). Then restart the service.

Comment: This was the only answer I could find on Stack Overflow which had correct instructions for configuring the timezone tables on Windows.  Even the MySQL documentation did not appear to contain this information.  Too bad I can only upvote this answer once +1

Comment: Copying the downloaded file into the folder did not work for me, but I found that it did work to open up HeidiSQL and just run the queries in the downloaded file on the mysql database.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else passing through here with the same issue on Mavericks I was getting the error mentioned by Anton whereby I kept getting;

```
ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 38981: Data too long for column 'Abbreviation' at row 1
```

So I used `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_file tz_name` from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) to load the specific time zones that I wanted;

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT GMT | mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC UTC | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

And now Django isn't returning errors so I'm happy :D

Answer (score 2):

The Django docs actually [talk about this problem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting):

> > I get an error “Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?” pytz is installed, so I guess the problem is my database?
>
> If you are using MySQL, see the [Time zone definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/databases/#mysql-time-zone-definitions) section of the MySQL notes for instructions on loading time zone definitions.

If you follow that link, you get this advice:

> If you plan on using Django’s timezone support, use `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` to load time zone tables into the MySQL database. This needs to be done just once for your MySQL server, not per database.

Here's the command:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading Time Zone for Mysql solved the problem for me.
If you are on windows, follow these instructions :

**Step #1: Download the package that contains the data files of pre-built time zone tables.**
 http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

**Step #2: Unzip the downloaded ZIP file to a folder on your Desktop.**

**Step #3: Stop MySQL Server.**

For Xampp and Wamp use their GUI or stop the mysql service from the Task Manager.

**Step #4: Open mysql subdirectory of your MySQL server's data directory.**

For me it is `C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql`

**Step #5: Overwrite time zone data files with the downloaded version.**

Copy all 15 data files from your unzipped folder and paste into data folder for the mysql system database. Overwrite all these .frm, .MYD, and .MYI files.

**Step #6: Restart MySQL server.**

And the job is done :-)

source : http://www.geeksengine.com/article/populate-time-zone-data-for-mysql.html