# Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.datetimes()

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, paypal

I got this error when I try to access the PayPal IPNs from the admin site.

```
ValueError at /admin/ipn/paypalipn/
    Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.datetimes(). Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://myapp.appspot.com/admin/ipn/paypalipn/
    Django Version: 1.9
    Exception Type: ValueError
    Exception Value:    
    Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.datetimes(). Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
    Exception Location: /base/data/home/apps/e~myapp/1.397535426774028716/lib/django/db/models/expressions.py in convert_value, line 945
    Python Executable:  /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/python
    Python Version: 2.7.5
    Python Path:    
    ['/base/data/home/apps/e~myapp/1.397535426774028716',
     '/base/data/home/apps/e~myapp/1.397535426774028716/lib',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.5',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/ssl-2.7',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
     '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']
    Server time:    Fri, 30 Dec 2016 22:09:03 +0000
```

I use Google Mysql and I've tried this answer [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351251/database-returned-an-invalid-value-in-queryset-dates) on Google Cloud Shell.

```
mysql> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -u root -p 
    -> "flush tables;" 
    -> flush tables;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm
ysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -u root -p 
"flush tabl' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: You really need to have a look at the guidance on creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question, it's completely impossible to assist as it is.

Comment: @Withnail I've edited my question I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Is the problem calling it from admin, or running mysql commands? These are likely related but different problems/solutions.

Comment: It's actually coming from a call from the admin when i try to access PayPal IPNs section

Comment: So you need to include your model for that, then.  Are there any model managers? Is this an external library you're using?

Comment: Actually it is django-paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution you Googled should be working, but you wrongly did it.

I'll show them again here, but to clarify, the steps below are all copied from the question description.

Steps:

1. In your **system command line** instead of MySQL's command-line interface, type
   `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -uroot -p`, so you will see something like this:

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -D mysql -uroot -p
   ```
2. (optional) Check if the problem is already solved. If not,  enter **MySQL command-line** by `mysql -uroot -p` in your system, and then type `flush tables;`. Your screen will look like this:

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu$ mysql -uroot -p
   Enter password:
   ...
   mysql> flush tables;
   ```