# Error with Mysql datetime in django extract return None

Tags: django, django-models

[Image captured when i try with django manage.py shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vx5p.png)

I try to extract month,day from Datetime field django model. But it return None. 
Help me. I have no idea.

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year

Comment: No, look at my image attach to the question, can you explain why ExtractMonth return None

Comment: Use Extract in annotation not values.

Comment: results is the same, return None

Comment: I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351251/database-returned-an-invalid-value-in-queryset-dates .

Comment: https://imgur.com/iK8nRqt