# Django annotate group by date return object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django's `annotate` from the [aggregate doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/).

My goal is to group a model by date and return all objects associated with each date in this form:

```
[{
  'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 11, 35), 
  'instances': [<Model: (1)>, <Model: (2)>  ]
},
{
  'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 11, 35),
  'instances': [<Model: (3)>, <Model: (6)>  ]
},]
```

I tried this query:

```
Flight.objects.values('origin_scheduled_dep').annotate(Count('origin_scheduled_dep')).order_by('origin_scheduled_dep')
```

But that's returning the `values` I specified:

```
<QuerySet [{'origin_scheduled_dep': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 11, 35), 'origin_scheduled_dep__count': 1}, {'origin_scheduled_dep': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 15, 40), 'origin_scheduled_dep__count': 1}, {'origin_scheduled_dep': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 22, 0), 'origin_scheduled_dep__count': 2}]>
```

Thanks for any help, always :)

Comment: In your sample output you're showing that you want the object instances themselves, but in your sample code you imply that you just want the count. Which is it?

Comment: In other words, `<Model: [id]>`, is the default string value of an instance, so implies that you have or want the instance. If you just want the count, your output might instead look something like `{'date': ..., 'instance_count': 2}`.

Comment: I'd like to return the actual model instance grouped by date where the date has it's own attribute value for all flights departing on that date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this using [**`TruncDate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate):

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Flight.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('origin_scheduled_dep')).values('date').annotate(count=Count('date')).order_by('date')
```

**FYI:** If you are using MySQL and using timezone support from django, then use `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` to load time zone tables into the MySQL database([**`reference`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#time-zone-definitions)). This [**`SO answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21571350/2696165) might help regarding this.

---

#### Update

I don't think your expected result is achievable using only django queryset functions. So, I think you need to use some python functions to achieve it, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict  
results = defaultdict(list)

queryset = Flight.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('origin_scheduled_dep')).order_by('date')

for flight in queryset:
    results[flight.date].append(flight)

for key, value in results.items():
     print(key,value)
```

Or you can use [**`regroup`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag to display a hierarchical list.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this returns only the flight object. I'd like them grouped by date like I showed in my question

Comment: Sorry, I missed `values('date')`. I have updated my answer

Comment: Actually this query still returns the count of the object instead of the objects itself. See the output i'd like to get in my question

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a mix of `TruncDate`, `order_by` and `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

queryset = Flight.objects.annotate(
   date=TruncDate('origin_scheduled_dep'),
).order_by('date')
grouped = [
    {'date': date, 'instances': instances}
    for date, instances in itertools.groupby(
       queryset.iterator(), attrgetter('date')
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work as you need but I don't think it is the best practice for the problem

```
from django.db.models import Count

times = Flight.objects.values_list('origin_scheduled_dep', flat=True).annotate(Count('origin_scheduled_dep'))
my_list = []

for time in times:
    my_list.append({'date': time, 'instances': Flight.objects.filter(origin_scheduled_dep=time)})
```

I tried to do this with Django ORM but I can't 
so i 
tested this for a dataset of 330000 with 820 repeated values and some values have more then 2200 instances and the time was good