# Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database installed?

Tags: mysql, django, windows

i tried to TruncDay in django to turn date into day format , i use `mysql` version `8.0` with `windows 10`
this my settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

MyModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('date'))#others
```

and i tried to run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql;` but it raise this error while i run this command in mysql shell

> ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql' at line 1

i also downloaded times files https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
and also my django project raise this error also

> Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database installed?

Comment: The command that begins `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` is meant to be run from the command line, not from within mysql.

Comment: no , you wrong you should type it in mysql shell

Comment: @art_cs nope, the `|`s are for the OS shell to run additional commands, the `mysql ...` would start a mysql shell session.

Comment: dont work you say (mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo mysql -u root mysql;)

Comment: @user3783243 may you explain more please

Comment: @art_cs The `|` is an operator in the linux shell (maybe windows?) and it pass the commands on the left to the function call on the right. So this is running `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo` then executing `mysql -u root mysql` which opens a mysql shell as the `mysql` user. This is meant for command line, not mysql shell.

Comment: didnt work in command line (cmd) in windows , and in in the mysql docs say to run in mysql shell

Comment: I think you are misreading the docs. `shell` is the linux shell, not `mysql` see the part `and send the output into the mysql program` it wouldn't need to send it to the program if it was being executed in the program. This may not be the right syntax for Windows.. The pipes are for linux execution.

Answer (score 1):

> Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database installed?

I got the same error after upgrading django from 2.2 to 3.2 and this was the first stack overflow question I found.

For me the following fixed the error:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21571350/10162645

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and MySQL Server 8.0
What I did was:

1. Download posix timezone sql from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
2. Do not move anything, just open this sql file in MySQL Workbench and add `USE mysql;` to the first line.
3. Run this file and that's it

Answer (score -1):

Just change the settings.py from

```
USE_TZ = True
```

to

```
USE_TZ = False
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is no solution to the problem, it's avoiding it. Answers from this post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351251/database-returned-an-invalid-value-in-queryset-dates/21571350#21571350